# How to change CComboBox edit control's height?

Tags: edit, ccombobox

CComboBox contains one text edit window and a dropdown window. I intend to change the text edit control's height. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I find the a solution that SetFont() can change font size, and edit window also adjust its size.

Answer (score 2):

Set font of Combobox control.

```
// *.h
CComboBox m_combo1;

// *.cpp    
CFont comboFont;
comboFont.Create(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_NATURAL_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, _T("Arial"));

m_combo1.SetFont(&comboFont);
...
```

Comment: cannot find comboFont.Create() but only comboFont.CreateFont(), thanks

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> Call the SetItemHeight member function to set the height of list items
>   in a combo box or the height of the edit-control (or static-text)
>   portion of a combo box.

```
m_comboBox.SetItemHeight( -1 /*edit control*/, 15 /*height in pixels*/ );
```