# Issues with adding a CComboBox to a CMFCStatusBar pane

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, statusbar

I have this simple code to create a `CComboBox` and display it on a pane in a `CMFCStatusBar`:

```
CRect rcPane;
m_StatusBar.GetItemRect(panePageBreaks, &rcPane);
CFont *pFont = m_StatusBar.GetFont();

m_myCombo.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, rcPane, &m_StatusBar, 2500);
m_myCombo.SetFont(pFont);
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: None"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 1 Week"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 2 Weeks"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 3 Weeks"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 4 Weeks"));
```

Can I make the status bar big enough to encompass this combo? At the moment it is a pixel or two too short in height:

[image: StatusBar]

---

## Update

If I use:

```
rcPane.InflateRect(1, 2, 0, 2);
```

It seems to be better. But i don't want to fudge it. Another users PC might be different. I want this combo to be exact over the specific pane.

---

## Update

I am kind of annoyed now. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684897/how-to-change-ccombobox-edit-controls-height) which implies doing two things:

1. Changing the font height.
2. Using `SetItemHeight`.

So I employed both of these and I found that I would need a font height of -6 for the control to have the right height:

```
CRect rcPane;
m_StatusBar.GetItemRect(panePageBreaks, &rcPane);
CFont *pFont = m_StatusBar.GetFont();
LOGFONT sLF;
pFont->GetLogFont(&sLF);
sLF.lfHeight = -6;
pFont->CreateFontIndirect(&sLF);

m_myCombo.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, rcPane, &m_StatusBar, 2500);
m_myCombo.SetItemHeight(-1, rcPane.Height());
m_myCombo.SetFont(pFont);
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: None"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 1 Week"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 2 Weeks"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 3 Weeks"));
m_myCombo.AddString(_T("Page Breaks: 4 Weeks"));
```

[image: Status Bar with Combo]

You see, you can set the height of the edit control, but if your font height is larger it will make the edit control larger. So I can't go over -6. And the status bar text is -12. So this is not an option.

All I was trying to do was provide an easy way for the user to change this setting via the status bar as well as via menu navigation. But it looks like I can't do it.

If anything the `CMFCStatusBar` height needs to be a tad taller than the default `CComboBox` edit control height.

Comment: Which height do you need adjusted? A combo box has 2 heights (see [Why does the size of a combo box include the size of the drop-down?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060310-17/?p=31973)).

Comment: @IInspectable I don’t mind the drop-down bit being automatically worked out. It is the basic combo / edit control. As you can see we can’t see the bottom border line. Not unless I fudge the CRect.

Comment: @Andrew: there is another solution: to increase the statusbar height, which could be made easily ... in this way, everything you put there will look fine ...I don't know if is ok with you.

Comment: @flaviu2 I don't know how to change the `CMFCStatusBar` height.

Comment: I wrote you a little code that show you how to increase the statusbar height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code show how to increase the height of the statusbar. In this way you can use the stardard controls in your statubar without any modification.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CMDIFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (!m_wndStatusBar.Create(this))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
    m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT));

    m_wndStatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetMinHeight(70); // or, whatever you need

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried: `CRect rctCombo; m_cbChairman.GetWindowRect(&rctCombo);  m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetMinHeight(rctCombo.Height()+4);` And it looks good. Not sure why I had to add 4 and whether it would always be 4 for all screens?

Comment: I guess rctCombo.Height() + 4 is ok for all screens, is about the lines from below and above the control (combobox or whatever).